# How to refer picklist values in apex, so that they will be easier to find later in codebase

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-field, custom

I'm working on a statndard object like **Opportunity**, where I have a picklist lets say **Status__c** on it.

Since Opportunity is a common object for multiple teams, Status field it is being used in the code base a lot.

I want to write some apex on a new Status value called **"Pseudo Approved"**, but i'm not sure this picklist field's value will be used for a long time. (I'm expecting it to be deleted from field level itself)

I am looking for a solution where someone from other team when have to **delete/replace the picklist value, should be prompted with my apex code** saying its been used here.

Currently I can just declare it as a final string constant and refer that const variable so that they dont have to replace it everywhere, is there a better solution to this.

I am looking for direct refering the picklist value so that apex knows its a picklist value and not just normal string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to statically reference a picklist value, to check if that will appear when trying to delete the picklist value with no success. So there is no standard option to prompt the user when deleting a picklist value

Maybe your best option is to create a test method that detects if that picklist value exists. This will allow the other developer to update that value in a Sandbox but will appear when trying to run tests in a deployment

Then in your test method, you can specify further instructions, like where is that picklist value used, and what changes are necessary to do